# I would like my Jquery script of show/hide to always display one of the hiddent conent and never display more then 1 hiddent text at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I would like this Show/hide script to show the first hidden text on startup and at all times only show max one hidden content. So if im displaying the hidden content of text 3 and before i was viewing the hidden content of text 1 i know want the text 1 to slide back up if i press text 3, all in same .slidetoggle i have now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".neverseen img").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
                $(".neverseen p").slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".neverseen1 img").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
                $(".neverseen1 p").slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".neverseen2 img").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
                $(".neverseen2 p").slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".neverseen3 img").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
                $(".neverseen3 p").slideToggle("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

```css
#leftpanel h1 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887; border-top: 1px solid #b0a887; font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel p {display: none; color: #333; font-size: 14px;}
#leftpanel a {margin-left: 230px;}
#leftpanel img {}

.secondImage{
  display: none;
}

.active .firstImg{
  display:none;
}

.active .secondImage {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftpanel">
                <div class="neverseen">
                    <h1>First title</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="show">
                        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                    </a>
                    <p>First text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="neverseen1">
                    <h1>Second title</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="show1">
                        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                    </a>
                    <p>Second text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="neverseen2">
                    <h1>Third title</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="show2">
                        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                    </a>
                    <p>Third text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="neverseen3">
                    <h1>Last title</h1>
                    <a href="#" id="show3">
                        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
                    </a>
                    <p>Last text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in another answer, you can use accordion but if you don't want to change your approach you do following,

add **sec** class to **neverseen{1/2/3}** div's like

```
<div id="leftpanel">
  <div class="sec neverseen">
    <h1>First title</h1>
    <a href="#" id="show" class='active'>
        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <p class='active'>First text</p>
</div>
<div class="sec neverseen1">
    <h1>Second title</h1>
    <a href="#" id="show1">
        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <p>Second text</p>
</div>
<div class="sec neverseen2">
    <h1>Third title</h1>
    <a href="#" id="show2">
        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <p>Third text</p>
</div>
<div class="sec neverseen3">
    <h1>Last title</h1>
    <a href="#" id="show3">
        <img class="secondImage" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
        <img class="firstImg" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <p>Last text</p>
</div>
```

Now we don't have to add events for individual sections, we can add it on **sec** class

```
$(".sec img").click(function() {
    var isActive = $(this).parent().hasClass('active');
    $('.sec a').removeClass('active');
    $('.sec p').hide('slideUp');
    if(!isActive) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("active"); 
      $(this).parent().next("p").slideToggle("slow");
    }

    return false;
});
```

Add this CSS at the end,

```
#leftpanel p.active{
  display: block;  
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/dufozazame/edit?html,js,console,output)

What I am doing here is that I am attaching event to all images under **sec** div.

When someone click on that, I am setting active class on parent div and resetting every other div.

Comment: This was a very easy and nice fix, just one problem, is it possible to get the first " sec neverseen" to always show on startup so that when people enter the page with this script on the first hiddent content is visible.

Comment: Updated my answer for the default state. Basically defined another active class for paragraph and added active to both visible by default elements.

Comment: Beautiful works flawless :) if i want to get picky and make it look really nice, id like to add so that it forces atleast 1 of the hidden content to always be visible.. for example if im having one of the content visible only  and i close it nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple accordion for this.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

[Here is an example.](http://uniondesign.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/accordion-demo.html)