# Straggling with Bootstrap to complete my show/hide accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

Okay I started with  **Bootstrap** today and got some help to start getting one toggle working but I need 4 of them working properly. The problem as you see if you run the code only the first window reveals information, the second thing I need help with is to make so that went it works only one hidden text can be shown at a time, third thing I need help with is for the first hidden text to be visible on page load. * This is not a duplicate post the last solution i got worked fine but wasnt very responsive and it was quite laggy, decided to try Bootstrap and it looks very promising.

```css
#leftpanel h1 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887; border-top: 1px solid #b0a887; font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel h2 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887;  font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel a {margin-left: 230px;}
#demo { color: #333; font-size: 14px;}



.collapse {}
.testver { }

.testver hr {


}

.fa-angle-up {
  display: none;
}

.testver i {

}

 .testver .fa {
   ;
 }

 .arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-up {
   display: inline-block;
 }

  .arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-down {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftpanel">
                <div class="testver">
                    <h1>First title</h1>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        First text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Second title</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        Second text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Third title</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        Third text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="testver">
                    <h2>Last title</h2>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        Last Text
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I would like my Jquery script of show/hide to always display one of the hiddent conent and never display more then 1 hiddent text at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296984/i-would-like-my-jquery-script-of-show-hide-to-always-display-one-of-the-hiddent)

Comment: No because the solution i got did work but was very laggy and not very responsive, i got a tip from another guy about Bootstrap and it seems very promising but i have very limit knowledge about it..

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap check this , https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion , there is an example there which you can use.

Comment: Thanks @GeekAb will def check that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDs must be unique: so change #demo to #demo1, #demo2, #demo3 and #demo4 just for instance.

After clicking a div it's necessary to hide all the remaining divs:

```
var currTarget = $(this).closest('a').data('target').substr(1);
$('#leftpanel').find('[id^="demo"]').not(currTarget).collapse('hide');
```

In order to set open the first div it's necessary to add the collapse in property plus aria-expamded like in:

```
<div id="demo1" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
```

The snippet:

```js
$('.testver a i').on('click', function(e) {
  var currTarget = $(this).closest('a').data('target').substr(1);
  $('#leftpanel').find('[id^="demo"]').not(currTarget).collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
#leftpanel h1 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887; border-top: 1px solid #b0a887; font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel h2 {font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Montserrat bold'; color:#b0a887;  font-style: normal;}
#leftpanel a {margin-left: 230px;}
#demo { color: #333; font-size: 14px;}



.collapse {}
.testver { }

.testver hr {


}

.fa-angle-up {
  display: none;
}

.testver i {

}

.testver .fa {
  ;
}

.arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-up {
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-angle-down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="leftpanel">
    <div class="testver">
        <h1>First title</h1>


        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" aria-expanded="true">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demo1" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
            First text
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="testver">
        <h2>Second title</h2>


        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
            Second text
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="testver">
        <h2>Third title</h2>


        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
            Third text
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="testver">
        <h2>Last title</h2>


        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"><img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" width="40" height="40"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="demo4" class="collapse">
            Last Text
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked flawless thank you VERY much! i obv tried changing the id's but totally forgot about the data-target :( thx tho